# ColdFusion Builder 2 Client Error - Memory Leak/Loop on Edit

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I've not found any other resources on this issue, so I figured I would ask the SO community. :)

I currently have an issue with my CFB2 client going into a memory leak about three seconds after I edit a particular file on one of our company webservers. This also occurs when I try and edit a local copy of the file. The leak is slow and would take many many hours to hold up all of my free RAM (~6.5GB/8GB physical). There is also a high CPU usage on the leak (anywhere from 25-45% | 1.8 GHz four-core). The only visual feedback I receive is in the Outline pane, where it extends infinitely into a loop of `cfelseif` tags. The pane also holds the loop before editing, but does not attempt to extend it.

This error first occurred whilst I was creating a `cffile` tag and because I could not close it, the conditional statements were mis-highlighted. I believe this is the root cause of the issue, however, I do not know why this occurred.

As I complete typing of this, I will move the file to a simple editor, remove the line that caused the error, and attempt to add it again, however I fear that the addition of the line will end in the same manner.

EDIT: I moved the page source into Notepad and removed the pesky `cffile` line. Then, I proceeded to delete the file from the webserver, create a new file of the same name, and add the code back. I closed the tag before adding any attributes just to ensure the same issue would not occur, and it did not experience the same loop.

Comment: What is the behavior in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm unsure. I do not have Eclipse on this machine. I'm fairly new to production development and was told by my supervisor to use CFB2. However, I believe I'll download Eclipse just to have a secondary IDE. :)

Comment: Well, CFB is based on Eclipse, so it would be really interesting to see what happens. It might be a good test for this specific problem.